# 500 error when trying to reconcile Office 365 licenses

Tags: office-365, licensing

When we click on this:

[image: Check your Office 365 Licenses]

We receive this message:

[image: 500 - Internet server error.]

How can we reconcile our Office 365 licenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Microsoft support via the Office 365 admin center. This is a server-side error and nothing we'll be able to help with.